# JSONObject as request body in Spring mvc with jersey(jackson)

Tags: java, json, jackson, jersey

I recently got to know that Jackson mapper can not get you a JSONObject into your code. Most of the time I have used custom POJOs to get the request body so this was surprising to me. Please excuse if this is a naive question.

```
public Response anyPOSTApi( @RequestBody org.json.JSONObject json) {...}
```

If you try the above code, you would get an empty JSONObject always.

I would like to know the reason behind this (Do not need a workaround as of now)? Or is there any specific dependency to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

@RequestBody maps body data to method arguments only if argument class fields name is matching to keys of query in request body. Otherwise u have to register your Own DataBinder 
 using @initBinder annotated method which will bind request body data to your argument.